# How to rewrite a URL in Drupal...?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal, url-rewriting, drupal-7

I have two search forms(Form 1:user_search, Form 2:property_search ) in the following url path

`http://dev.test.com/custom_search_page`

When i search for user the url redirects to

`http://dev.test.com/view-user-search?field_user_value=test`

likewise  When i search for property the url redirects to

`http://dev.test.com/view-property-search?field_location_value=test`

The URLs should not be like this. It should be rewritten as

`http://dev.test.com/custom_search_page?field_location_value=test`

How to rewrite the URLs...?

Comment: How could you make a difference between `user` and `property` search with one common `custom_search_page` ?

Comment: i need the urls to be rewritten for the both as custom_search_page.

Comment: You did not answer my question...

Comment: can't understand your question.

Comment: Well, if i go to `http://domain.tld/custom_search_page?field_location_value=test` how does *mod_rewrite* know if it has to rewrite to `view-user-search` or `view-property-search` ?

Comment: the parameters will be different for the searches...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61059/discussion-between-mukil-and-justin-iurman).

Comment: Then you should update your question with all the details we need to answer your question

Comment: i have changed the parameters...